# Append a counter to a variable whenever explanatory variables change

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame like this one in r:

```
df <- data.frame(policy_ID = c("P1","P1","P1","P2","P2","P3","P4","P4","P4","P4"), 
                 City = c("Copenhagen", "Copenhagen", "London", "LA", "LA",
                          "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Rome", "Milan"),
                 Floor = c("1","1","1","3","4","2","1","1","4","4"))
```

I want to have some change in policy_ID if the value of either City or Floor changes. **Desired output** looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(policy_ID = c("P1","P1","P1_2","P2","P2_2","P3","P4","P4","P4_2","P4_3"), 
                 City = c("Copenhagen", "Copenhagen", "London", "LA", "LA",
                          "Tokyo", "Madrid", "Madrid", "Rome", "Milan"),
                 Floor = c("1","1","1","3","4","2","1","1","4","4"))
```

Does anyone have an idea of how this can be done?

I've managed to produce this piece of code that spits out a 1 if a change has been made:

```
df %>%
  group_by(policy_ID) %>%
  mutate(City_or_Floor_changed = ifelse(City != lag(City, default = first(City)) | 
                                        Floor != lag(Floor, default = first(Floor)), 
                                      1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

However, I am struggling to figure out how to change the policy_ID as I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `rleid` to create the index

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(policy_ID2 = policy_ID) %>%
   mutate(tmp = rleid(City, Floor), 
   policy_ID = case_when(tmp > 1 ~ str_c(policy_ID, '_', tmp), 
      TRUE ~ policy_ID), .by = policy_ID2) %>% 
   select(-tmp, - policy_ID2)
```

-output

```
   policy_ID       City Floor
1         P1 Copenhagen     1
2         P1 Copenhagen     1
3       P1_2     London     1
4         P2         LA     3
5       P2_2         LA     4
6         P3      Tokyo     2
7         P4     Madrid     1
8         P4     Madrid     1
9       P4_2       Rome     4
10      P4_3      Milan     4
```

Answer (score 4):

A second option would be to use `dplyr::consecutive_id` which was introduced in `dplyr 1.1.0` and is inspired by `data.table::rleid`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

df |>
  mutate(run = consecutive_id(City, Floor), .by = policy_ID) |>
  mutate(
    policy_ID = if_else(run > 1,
      paste(policy_ID, run, sep = "_"),
      policy_ID
    )
  )
#>    policy_ID       City Floor run
#> 1         P1 Copenhagen     1   1
#> 2         P1 Copenhagen     1   1
#> 3       P1_2     London     1   2
#> 4         P2         LA     3   1
#> 5       P2_2         LA     4   2
#> 6         P3      Tokyo     2   1
#> 7         P4     Madrid     1   1
#> 8         P4     Madrid     1   1
#> 9       P4_2       Rome     4   2
#> 10      P4_3      Milan     4   3
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for *laffs*, here's an answer using `lag` and `cumsum`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(tmp = cumsum(City != lag(City, default = "null") | 
                      Floor != lag(Floor, default = "null")), 
         policy_ID = case_when(tmp == 1 ~ policy_ID,
                               TRUE ~paste(policy_ID, tmp, sep = "_")),
         .by = policy_ID) %>% 
  select(-tmp)
```

```
#>    policy_ID       City Floor
#> 1         P1 Copenhagen     1
#> 2         P1 Copenhagen     1
#> 3       P1_2     London     1
#> 4         P2         LA     3
#> 5       P2_2         LA     4
#> 6         P3      Tokyo     2
#> 7         P4     Madrid     1
#> 8         P4     Madrid     1
#> 9       P4_2       Rome     4
#> 10      P4_3      Milan     4
```